# Method with same name and different return type is achieved in c# but not in java

Tags: java, c#

I am new to JAVA environment, am facing issue while trying to implement method with same name and different return type. In C# I have used method hiding concept to achieve this. Is there any better way to implement the same in JAVA. Please find the code snippet for reference. Please advise me in this

C#:

```
class Shape
{
public int Width { get; set; }
public int Height { get; set; }

public void Print()
{
Console.WriteLine("Base class is called");
}
}


class Table: Shape
{
public int m_tableHeight;
public int m_tableWidth;
public string m_modle;

public Table(int tableWidth, int tableHeight,string modle)
{
m_tableHeight = tableHeight;
m_tableWidth = tableWidth;
m_modle = modle;
}

public new string Print()
{
return m_modle;
}
}
```

JAVA:

```
public class Shape
{
public int getWidth()throws Exception{
return getWidth();
}
public void setWidth(int value)throws Exception{
setWidth(value);
}
public int getHeight()throws Exception{
return getHeight();
}
public void setHeight(int value)throws Exception{
setHeight(value);
}
public void Print()throws Exception{
System.out.println("Base class is called");
}
}

public class Table
 extends Shape
{
public  int m_tableHeight;
public  int m_tableWidth;
public  String m_modle;
public Table(int tableWidth,int tableHeight,String modle)throws Exception{
m_tableHeight=tableHeight;
m_tableWidth=tableWidth;
m_modle=modle;
}
//Throws error as return type is incompatible with shape.print()
public String Print()throws Exception{
return m_modle;
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't added a code snipet

Comment: I have attached the code snippet, please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Java methods are identified by there method descriptor: the method descriptor consists of class and method name as well as the type of the method parameters, but the return type is not part of the method descriptor!

So in Java you can not have two methods with same name, same parameters (but different return type) in one class. (Of course on method can override an other method and narrow* the return type, but this is overriding not overloading)

*(* you can only narrow them (override a method that returns Number with an Method that returns Double) but you can not change them and you can not override a method that return void with an method that return something else)*